# Can't login to 11.04 ~90% of the time

Tags: 11.04, drivers, compiz, graphics, radeon

Since I installed Ubuntu 11.04, one of the following things happen when I try to login:

- I see my wallpaper and my mouse cursor, but nothing else loads. Every ~10-20 seconds, the screen goes black for about one second, then shows just my wallpaper and mouse cursor again. This happens about 60% of the time that I try to log in.
- I see my wallpaper and my mouse cursor, but after ~10-20 seconds, the screen goes black and stays black until I turn off my computer. This happens about 15% of the time that I try to login in.
- I see a screen like the one in the below image (open the image in a new tab to see it in greater detail). I believe it is warning about a problem with compiz or my radeon drivers. This happens about 15% of the time that I try to log in.

[image]

- Login is successful. This happens about 10% of the time that I try to log in.

I see the problem both in the "Unity" session and the "Ubuntu Classic" session. It does not appear to occur in "Ubuntu Classic (no effects)", but I have not tested that exhaustively.

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 with latest updates on a Dell Studio XPS 16. My videocard is a Radeon HD 4670. The full result of `sudo lshw -sanitize` is [here](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/419105/).

Does anyone know what's going on? I apologize if this is the wrong place for such a question. I thought that I should report on Launchpad bugs, but `ubuntu-bug` requested that I ask on this site before filing a bug.

Comment: It's safe to say that you are hitting a bug. All we need to do now is to determine if that bug already has been reported or is a new one.

Comment: There you go: [bug 783458](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/783458). Subscribe, mark yourself as affected by the bug. This question will be closed as askubuntu.com is the wrong platform for bugs.

Comment: Thanks, @htorque. Out of curiosity, why does `ubuntu-bug` now point me to askubuntu.com? I suspected that askubuntu was the wrong platform for this question, but was thrown off by `ubuntu-bug`'s directions.

Comment: I have not the slightest idea. :-)

Comment: I'm over-simplifying things but ubuntu-bug is trying to get users to research things as much as possible before they file a bug. While that's a noble gesture  the-powers-that-be seemingly think it's better to fill up AU with bug reports before they accept a bug on LaunchPad, which is just moving the problem. In short, somebody needs to improve the language ubuntu-bug uses. I hope you get a fix, anyway.